# Check if multiple values are not in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to check if a value isn't in a column. Currently I am doing this:

> WHERE `type` != 'internal-link' AND `type` != 'external-link' AND `type` != 'home-link' ..

It goes on. There are 20 types and I need to make sure the type isn't 8 of them. Is there some kind of in_array function for MySQL?

Something like:

> WHERE `type` != ['internal-link', 'external-link', 'home-link'] ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE type NOT IN ('internal-link', 'external-link', 'home-link' )
```